# What is the most pythonic way to pass UI data to a `tkinter` GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

As a way to teach myself Python, I have dusted off some of my old undergraduate mechanical engineering texts and am creating some calculators for some simple concepts.  Say I have a calculator class like (very simple for brevity):

```
from math import pi
import tkinter as tk


class Cylinder(object):

    """Abstraction of a cylinder primitive."""

    def __init__(self):
        """See class docstring."""
        self.radius = 0.0
        self.height = 0.0

    def calc_volume(self):
        """See class docstring."""
        self.volume = pi * self.height * self.radius**2
```

and now I want to wrap this in a `tkinter` gui.   There is potentially a large number of calculators in my project and I certainly don't want to code custom wrappers for each calculator, so I am trying to develop a content agnostic approach.  So, I started by writing:

```
class CalcGUI(tk.Frame):

    """To do. Write me."""

    def __init__(self, master=None, calc_object=None):
        """See class docstring."""
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        self.entries, self.entry_vars = {}, {}
        for num, item in enumerate(calc_object.__dict__):
            tk.Label(self, text=item).grid(row=num, column=0)
            self.entry_vars[item] = tk.StringVar()
            self.entries[item] = tk.Entry(self,
                                          textvariable=self.entry_vars[item])
            self.entries[item].grid(row=num, column=1)
```

This works fine for simple variable names like `radius`, but for more complicated items, I don't want to muddle the calculators with long variable names like `self.coefficient_of_thermal_expansion` or `self.average_air_velocity_of_a_coconut_laden_swallow`, so I would like an elegant way to pass what I would consider UI information to the GUI, like English name, expected units, etc. and am looking for some best practices.  Some options I've considered:

- Make all of the variables `tuples` or `namedtuples` with slots for English Name, Value and Units.

  - I think this will complicate the calculation logic too much and really reduce readability.
- Create a class level dict containing all of the UI config info for the calculator class.

  - This keeps the readability within the calculator class, but means I am storing things in the class that aren't really used within the class (seems unPythonic to me).
- Create a separate config module will the settings for everything.

  - This keeps the calculator classes nice and tidy, but may reduce readability inside the GUI module.

Which of these (if any!) would be considered best practice within Python?

**Edit** Why not long variables?
consider the following equation for beam deflection:

- `y = (3 * a - x) * (P * x**2) / (6 * E * I)`

putting that in a class method you could write something like:

- `self.y = (3 * self.a - self.x) * (self.P * self.x**2) / (6 * self.E * self.I)`

or with long variables:

- `self.beam_deflection = ((3 * self.force_location - self.location_on_beam) * 
                          (self.point_force * self.location_on_beam**2) / 
                          (6 * self.modulus_of_elasticity * self.moment_of_inertia))`

I personally think the first option is much more readable.  That said, there is no reason I could not alias the vars like: `E = self.modulus_of_elasticity`

but that still only solves one piece of the puzzle.  It doesn't address units or other items (say a flag for whether a variable should be entered as an Entry or Listbox, etc).

Comment: Python isn't assembly - there's nothing wrong with long variable names. When you see `self.average_air_velocity_of_a_coconut_laden_swallow`, you'll know for sure that it refers to the average air velocity of a coconut-laden swallow. Contrast that with `self.calc_vars[2]` or `self.calc_vars['cl_sw_vel']`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, good point and certainly worth remembering, however I think I'm not sure I was quite going the way you did.  I added some clarification as to why I was thinking of shying away from long var names.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "readable." If you believe that brevity increases readability, then the first beam deflection equation is best. If you believe that readability is determined by the quality of the information, then the second equation is best. Most decent text editors or IDEs provide some kind of completion, anyway (e.g., start typing `self.be` and get a suggestion of `self.beam_deflection`).